# Silverlight 5 ComboBox ToggleButton Focused VisualState not working

Tags: xaml, combobox, silverlight-5.0, togglebutton, visualstates

I can't figure out why the FocusVisualElement of the ComboBox ToggleButton never shows. I've tried moving the Focused Storyboard to MouseOver and it works then, so I'm pretty sure the storyboard works. Perhaps the Focused VisualState is never firing? I've included my style below. Thanks for your help!

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5,5,25,5"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Thin"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFCCCCCC"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF222222"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF666666"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Name="comboToggleStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF000000"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="PressedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1"/>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckedBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                            <Storyboard>
                                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement">
                                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>                                                                
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </VisualState>
                                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="Background" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="MouseOverBackground" Opacity="0" Stroke="#FF888888" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="PressedBackground" Opacity="0" Fill="#FF0096db" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="#00000000"/>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledBackground" Opacity="0" Fill="#FF222222" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="#00000000"/>
                                                <Rectangle x:Name="CheckedBackground" Opacity="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="#00000000"/>

                                                <ContentPresenter
                                                      x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>

                                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Stroke="#FF0096db" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Visibility="Collapsed" IsHitTestVisible="false"/>

                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" >
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <sys:Boolean>True</sys:Boolean>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentPresenterBorder">
                            <Grid>
                                <ToggleButton x:Name="DropDownToggle" Style="{StaticResource comboToggleStyle}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                    <Path x:Name="BtnArrow" Height="4" Width="8" Stretch="Uniform" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "
                                          Margin="0,0,6,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Fill="#FFCCCCCC"/>
                                </ToggleButton>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" 
                                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"  
                                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                    <TextBlock Text=" " />
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="White" Opacity="0" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
                        <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" Template="{StaticResource CommonValidationToolTipTemplate}" Placement="Right" 
                                           PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                           DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                    <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" >
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                <sys:Boolean>true</sys:Boolean>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <Grid Width="12" Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent">
                                <Path Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C"/>
                                <Path Margin="1,3,0,0" Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                            <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0">
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```